# Spark Kafka Stream error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new Spark and Kafka. I have done Spark and Kafka setup done in Windows system. Both are working good. I have followed below mentioned tutorial and executing the Scala code in Spark-shell and getting below mentioned error.

Can anybody help me on how to listen Kafka stream using Spark in Scala.

Spark : 2.2
Kafka : 2.12

http://www.godatafy.com/poc/streaming-with-spark-kafka/

**spark-shell -jars ..\jars\spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3.jar**

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

scala> sc.stop

scala> val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]")
sparkConf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@427c2c96

scala> val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext = org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@1fd73dcb

scala> val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test" -> 5))
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'KafkaUtils.class'.
Could not access term kafka in package <root>,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'KafkaUtils.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <root>.
```

Comment: are you sure kafka 2.12 ?

Comment: yes. I am using Kafka: 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kafka 0.10 or higher you need to add the jar to the version that supports spark 2.2

Use **`spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.10-2.2.0.jar`**

rather than *`spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3.jar`*

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: after using spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.11-1.6.3, I am getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging. why ?.

Comment: why did not you use `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.10-2.2.0.jar`

Comment: Can u give me maven repo url for spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.10-2.2.0.jar. not able to find in Maven repo. please

Comment: you can find the dependency here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.2.0

Comment: I used spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar, But while import ing import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils package getting error error: object kafka is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming. if possible give me better tutorial where I can learn this concept

Comment: I have been working with the spark streaming and kafka and I used the same dependency

Comment: I just downloaded spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar and starting Spark-shell using "spark-shell -jars ..\jars\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar" then I am importing packages in shell. getting error. I am not writing Scala coding . trying in REPL

Comment: I think its better to use IDE and with maven or sbt for the project manager

Comment: since I am new to this I am trying with REPL.

Comment: Its ok, but with the use of IDE its more easier to use and start.

Comment: I tried with IDE import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
these imports are not part of given JAR it seems. Can u please provide me correct example for this JAR

Comment: Best help will be give me tutorial where I can see correct dependency and sample code for Kafka with Spark. thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this will be good to start  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html